# Cannot build watchOS extension

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, icarousel, watchos-3

I am adding WatchOS version to an already existing iOS App. I'm developing using Swift and using iCarousel, an Objective-C library, I added that manually by copying the .h and .m files in my project. Added .h file in my bridging header. The problem occurs while building.

[image]

The WatchKit Extension target creates an issue.  It says

> 'QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h' file not found

And that's inside iCarousel.h file on top where QuartzCore is imported. Thanks in Advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore) of Core Animation shows (QuartzCore is Core Animation), it is not available for `watchOS` at the moment (`watchOS 4`), so you cannot use the iCarousel framework on `watchOS`, since it uses Core Animation, which is unavailable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So now I have to ignore it for watchOS target.

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, you'll have to look for an alternative solution for watchOS.